# How can I start the pine script on tradingview?

Tags: pine-script, binance, binance-chain

I am beginner on Tradingview.
I am going to make a script to display the binance liquidity pool.
https://paguertrading.com/pools/
This my reference site and it is using the Bitmex data but I need to use Binance data.
If you have any solution for this problem, please help me.
Binance API is ready.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use data for which there is a corresponding feed on TV. Afawk, there is no feed like you need on TV.

Comment: So, it is impossible?